# adding colour and text inside a node of a neural network

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have the following structure of the neural network, But I would like to modify it and colour all input nodes as black and write f(x) inside the hidden nodes.  Kindly guide me on how to attain it.

[image]

to something like this

[image]

```
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \tikzset{%
      every neuron/.style={
        circle,
        draw,
        minimum size=1cm
      },
      neuron missing/.style={
        draw=none, 
        scale=4,
        text height=0.333cm,
        execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
      },
    }
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.3cm, y=1.3cm, >=stealth]
    
    \foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3,missing,4}
      \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};
    
    \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
      \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m) at (2,2-\y*1.25) {};
    
    
    \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2,missing,3}
      \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m) at (4,2.0-\y) {};
    
    \foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,j}
      \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
        node [above, midway] {$I_\l_f$};
    
    \foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,k}
      \node [above] at (hidden-\i.north) {$H_\l_f$};
    
    
    \foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,l}
      \draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
        node [above, midway] {$O_\l_f$};
        
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
      \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
        \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);
    
    \foreach \i in {1,...,2}
      \foreach \j in {1,...,3}
        \draw [->] (hidden-\i) -- (output-\j);
    
    \foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Input, Hidden, Output}
      \node [align=center, above] at (\x*2,2) {\l \\ layer};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: would you like to accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}


\tikzset{%
    every neuron/.style={
        circle,
        draw,
        minimum size=1cm
    },
    neuron missing/.style={
        draw=none, fill=none,%<-----------------new
        scale=4,
        text height=0.333cm,
        execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.3cm, y=1.3cm, >=stealth]
    
    \foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3,missing,4}
    \node [fill=black!20, every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try, ] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};%<-----fill=
    
    \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
    \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m) at (2,2-\y*1.25) {};
    
    
    \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2,missing,3}
    \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m) at (4,2.0-\y) {};
    
    \foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,j}
    \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$I$};
    
    \foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,k}
    \node [above] at (hidden-\i.north) {$H$};
    
    
    \foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,l}
    \draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$O$};
    
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);
    
    \foreach \i in {1,...,2}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,3}
    \draw [->] (hidden-\i) -- (output-\j);
    
    \foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Input, Hidden, Output}
    \node [align=center, above] at (\x*2,2) {\l \\ layer};
    \node (nx1) at (hidden-1) {$\mathbf{f_x}$};%<---------------new
    \node (nx2) at (hidden-2) {$\mathbf{f_x}$};%<---------------new
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```